# check current view controller over screen in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have presented a UINavigationController containing UIViewController on self object with following code

```
  drawController = [[DrawImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[drawController setDrawControllerDelegateObject:self];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:drawController];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
[nav release];
```

But when before calling the above code for second time i wanna know whether the current view controller appearing on screen is drawController. I am using following code

```
    if (drawController && [drawController isBeingPresented])
```

But it is not working for me and also it is for iOS 5.0 so i am stuck here. Please help me to know how should i come to know the current UIViewController appeared on screen is of which class and whether drawContoller is still presented on screen or not? Sorry for my typo mistakes if there is any. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks Neha Mehta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the prettiest code, but this should work:

```
if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] &&
   ((UINavigationController *)self.presentedViewController).topViewController == drawController) {
   …
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `navigationController's visibleViewController property` and `isKindOfClass method` to know whats on `top`:

```
if([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[yourcontroller class]])
   //exists
else
   //not exists
```

Comment: I was getting this error very small but you need to include [] around the self.

Answer (score 3):

Check for `UINavigationController`s `visibleViewController` method.

For documentation, please see [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)